# How to store stable texts? like text or like integer which is specific for each text

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I want to store stable text which means only can be changed by owner of website for example:

**Example**

user will select options from select bar which is pure text for example (select film type that you want to watch,and user select comedy) should I store comedy text each time when user select it? or should write options' value like  integers?For example I write value 5 which is represent comedy when user select comedy I will insert database 5 instead of comedy .Which is best way?text or integer?

**Note**

if I use integer and if user want to what he choosed ,I have array which is contain what number represent which text and  I will write array[number] and I will comedy

Comment: This is highly case-dependent. If this data is going to be highly relational then store it as an integer... if it's just a property of another object then leave it as a string (it won't have much effect on data-use or query speeds if you index appropriately in the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have "normalized" "Comedy" to be "5", then use the 5.  If not, the string is probably ok.

Keep in mind that if you ever change the spelling of "comedy", things can break.  Or it you re-number it.

Comment: okay but in my system it is not actually comedy,it is some keywords that only developers should know to change something for users and user will not see anything,in this case should I avoid it because it spend more space in disk or should I continue with numbers which I write translation in the php page with comments (which is a little bit messy even you think there are a lot of thing like that)?

Comment: Do a `JOIN` in SQL to get the text.